# Organic Post Shares Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I need to find the organic post shares for an Instagram post. From the marketing API, I can find the number of [post shares](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/) I cannot find the shares for a post from the Instagram graph API.

Here are relevant links to the documentation. 
[insights for an ad](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters)
[action stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/)
[instagram business account insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights)
[instagram media insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media)

I expect that the instagram graph API has the organic post shares because the marketing API shows the number of post shares for a boosted post (non 0; confirmed in business manager and API).

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, this is unfortunately not possible with the Instagram Graph API for non-boosted postings.